# struts generating form elements from bean

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1

I have a Struts 1.2 Bean and a Bean code as below in JSP Page

**checkBox.jsp**

```
<logic:iterate property="userList" id="userDet" name="userDetails">
  <html:checkbox property="checked" name="userDet" indexed="true">
   <bean:write property="userName" name="userDet"></bean:write>
  </html:checkbox>
</logic:iterate>
```

The above code brings output as below

[image]

Now when I submit the form I want to carry out Javascript validation using ids of the checkbox.

How can I generate id for check box generated in JSP page By Bean?Is it possible to generate id attribute dynamically ?

Comment: By putting the attribute to the tag.

Comment: The best solution depends on how you want to actually validate. If you just want to ensure at least one checkbox is checked, I'd use a class. It also depends on whether or not you're using a JS library like jQuery/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the 'indexId' attribute (The name of a page scope JSP bean that will contain the current index of the collection on each iteration.
) of

```
<logic:iterate>
```

And use it inside the 'styleId' attribute of

```
<html:checkbox>
```

Like this:

```
<logic:iterate property="userList" id="userDet" name="userDetails" indexId="checkBoxIndex">
  <html:checkbox property="checked" name="userDet" indexed="true" styleId="checkBox<%= checkBoxIndex %>">
   <bean:write property="userName" name="userDet"></bean:write>
  </html:checkbox>
</logic:iterate>
```